# CSS - Bubble input searchbar like Pinterest

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search bar where the user enters a keyword, and I would like the keywords to be enclosed in a bubble with a cross on end to delete it as soon as he user presses space to enter another keyword. Something like whats done at the Pinterest search bar as shown in this image below.

[image]

I can make bubble in CSS around texts, but how to draw them from inside the input box is where I am stuck at.

Comment: Probably there is one container looking as an input. on the left are all tags and on the right is input with no border and no background. Voilà.

Comment: Check out the `Select2` library which has the tagging option, You can see it in action here - https://select2.github.io/examples.html  (Under "Tagging support" section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Select2](https://select2.github.io/) and [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) were both good alternatives but I found [Selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) to best fit my use case (highly customizable). Its easier to use, extendable with few dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

It is worth checking out the `Select2` library which has the tagging option, You can see it in action [here](http://select2.github.io/examples.html) (Under "Tagging support" section).

Alternatively you can checkout the below `CodePen` link on the `tag based search`

http://codepen.io/jonahvsweb/pen/LGVRaX

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 0):

Check friends list here: http://terrainformatica.com/formation/demo1.htm
I've made simple jQuery plugin for it while ago: http://terrainformatica.com/formation/js/jquery.list-input.js

Answer (score 0):

Check harvestHQ Chosen plugin:
https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/